# fundamental group for different path component

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I was reading Hatcher's Algebraic topology book, there is a statement about the fundamental group on different path connected component as follows:

> Since $\pi_{1}\left(X, x_{0}\right)$ involves only the path-component
> of $X$ containing $x_{0}$, it is clear that we can hope to find a
> relation between $\pi_{1}\left(X, x_{0}\right)$ and $\pi_{1}\left(X,
>  x_{1}\right)$ for two basepoints $x_{0}$ and $x_{1}$ only if $x_{0}$
> and $x_{1}$ lie in the same path-component of $X$.

This statement is reasonable,I try to make it a theorem and prove it,is it possible to prove this statment?For example for homology group on different component the direct sum of them isomorphic to the holomogy group of the whole space.

Comment: What do you want to prove? $\pi_1 (X , x_0)$ and $\pi_1 (X , x_1)$ are isomorphic if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are in the same path component. Take a path $\gamma$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$. Then $[x] \mapsto [\gamma] \cdot [x] \cdot [\gamma]^{-1}$ furnishes the isomorphism. To see that they are not necessarily isomorphic if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are not in the same path component, consider the disjoint union of a disc with $S^1$.

Comment: If you want to show that $\pi_1(X , x_0) \cong \pi_1 (C , x_0)$ where $C$ is a path component containing $x_0$, you just have to show that the inclusion $i : C \to X$ furnishes an isomorphism $i_* : \pi_1 (C , x_0) \to \pi_1(X , x_0)$. Hint: a path can't leave a path component. Use this to define $i_*^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to prove that if there is a path $\gamma$ between points $x_0$ and $x_1$ in $X$, then $\pi_1(X,x_0) \cong \pi_1(X,x_1)$, you can do the following:

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ be a path with $\gamma(0)=x_0$, $\gamma(1)=x_1$. Define
$$
\gamma_* : \pi_1(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_1), \quad [w] \mapsto [\gamma * w * \overline{\gamma}],
$$
where $\overline{\gamma} : [0,1] \to X$, with $\overline{\gamma}(t) := \gamma(1-t)$, and
$$
(\gamma * w * \overline{\gamma})(t) = 
\begin{cases}
\gamma(3t) & 0 \leq t \leq \frac13\\
w(3t-1) & \frac13 \leq t \leq \frac23\\
\gamma(3(1-t)) & \frac23 \leq t \leq 1
\end{cases}.
$$
The map $\gamma_*$ is well-defined, because if $w \sim w'$ are homotopic via a homotopy $H$, then we get $\gamma * w * \overline{\gamma} \sim \gamma * w' * \overline{\gamma}$, via the Homotopy $H' : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$, with
$$
H'(t,s) =
\begin{cases}
\gamma(3t) & 0 \leq t \leq \frac13\\
H(3t-1,s) & \frac13 \leq t \leq \frac23\\
\gamma(3(1-t)) & \frac23 \leq t \leq 1
\end{cases}.
$$
Next, we see that $\gamma_*$ defines a group homomorphism, since
$$
\gamma * (w * w') * \overline{\gamma} \sim \gamma * (w * (\overline{\gamma}*\gamma) * w') * \overline{\gamma} \sim (\gamma * w * \overline{\gamma}) * (\gamma * w' * \overline{\gamma}),
$$
where we used that $\overline{\gamma}*\gamma$ is homotopic to the constant path $c_{x_1}$ at $x_1$.

Lastly, we show that $\gamma_*$ is an isomorphism. We know that $\overline{\gamma}$ induces a map $\overline{\gamma}_* : \pi_1(X,x_1) \to \pi_1(X,x_0)$. We want to show that $\gamma_* \circ \overline{\gamma}_* = \text{id}_{\pi_1(X,x_1)}$. Take some $[w] \in \pi_1(X,x_1)$. Then, we get that
$$
(\gamma_* \circ \overline{\gamma}_*)([w]) = [ \gamma*\overline{\gamma}*w*\gamma*\overline{\gamma} ] = [c_{x_0}*w*c_{x_0}] = [w].
$$
Similarly, one shows that $\overline{\gamma}_* \circ \gamma = \text{id}_{\pi_1(X,x_0)}$.

Therefore, $\gamma_*$ is an isomorphism, so $\pi_1(X,x_0) \cong \pi_1(X,x_1)$. Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Perhaps it is worth to mention that the different paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ in general induce different isomorphisms $(\gamma_i)_* : \pi_(X,x_0) \to \pi_1(X,x_1)$.